# FICO Xpress Workbench won't work due to OS Catalina, produced error "spawn mosel ENOENT"

Tags: macos-catalina, mosel

I have a bit of a technical question here. Since upgrading to OS Catalina I have tried running my Xpress Workbench files and a warning pops up saying "It can't be opened because Apple cannot check for malicious software." When bypassing this and opening it anyway it produces an error whenever I run some code:

"spawn mosel ENOENT"

Has anyone else experienced this? and what does the error mean? I have been in touch with Apple support but they weren't that helpful, I have also been in touch with FICO (the developer of the programme) and they haven't experienced the problem before but are getting in touch with their dev team.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got this issue when i upgraded my macOS to Catalina. I couldn't run my mosel programs successfully.

In Catalina, any software installed outside of the Mac App Store is now checked every time it runs for malware and other problems. You can solve this by un-quarantining the Xpress workbench application.

Run this code on terminal of your mac - xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine "/Applications/FICO Xpress" (specify the location of the application in the quote).

It should be fine after this.